# /.fseventsd folder not present on MacOS Monterey - where is it now?

Tags: macos, filesystems, monitoring, macos-monterey

Getting no hits for .fseventsd in Finder or Terminal (`$ sudo find / -name .fseventsd`) On MacOS 12.4 and fseventsd is running ok (< 1% CPU). Time Machine switched on. (Edit: I have turned on show hidden files and can see the other '.' items in Finder/terminal.)

Google is not helping at all and so I must be overlooking something pretty fundamental, what?

Related - are there any recommended utilities for watching the Mac file system?

Edit: Attaching screenshot of root boot volume.

[image]

Comment: It's a hidden file. See [macos - What is the .fseventsd log for? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354039/what-is-the-fseventsd-log-for)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that's not it. I've updated above. Will check out FSEventsParser.

Comment: Open a folder in Finder at the root of your boot drive, hit `Cmd/Shift/.` [period/full stop] There it is [though you won't have access]. Spotlight won't find it because it doesn't search hidden files/folders. idk why Terminal doesn't find it because I never use Terminal for searches, I use [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) `sudo ls /.fseventsd` will let you see inside it, but it's full of "hex codes/UUIDs" idk what they do.

Comment: Thanks, already had `Cmd/Shift/.` enabled and does not show up. (I've now attached screenshot above.)

Comment: Ah, I just looked at this on Monterey & you're right, it's no longer there. It's probably on 'Macintosh HD' not 'Macintosh HD Data' but I have no idea how you get to that.

Comment: `$ sudo find / -name .fseventsd` returns NO hits.  
`$ sudo find / -name fseventsd` returns /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/Support/fseventsd. Running `strings` on that still shows multiple references to "/.fseventsd"
What's going on??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /.fseventsd seems to have been moved from the previous root location when viewing in the terminal.

The new location appears to be at:
*/System/Volumes/Data/.fseventsd/*

referenced: https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/dock.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).